# How to get access token with Server Side OAuth2 (implicit grant)?

Tags: c#, server-side, restsharp, oauth-2.0

How to obtain access token via C# code (using Rest sharp or any other tool) for Server side oauth?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my GitHub [`.NET Core ImplicitConsoleClient`](https://github.com/mateudu/IdentityServer4.ImplicitConsoleClient/blob/master/src/ImplicitConsoleClient/ImplicitClient.cs) sample.
You will probably need to change your authorization URL. I tested that solution yesterday with `ASP.NET Core` and `IdentityServer4`, so it additionaly passes `__RequestVerificationToken` parameter, which is required by `ASP.NET ASP.NET's AntiforgeryToken`.

Comment: How to change it for standart .net 4.6 project?

var dictionary =              Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Fragment);

Comment: I try to get token for Cutwise.com, the authorization page is https://cutwise.com/api/oauth/v2/auth/login

Comment: If I were you, I would run [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and log in using browser (e.g. Google Chrome), and after having analyzed Fiddler logs (I did that in order to code IdentityServer4 implicit client) customize the client. **@Up:** You can use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @TatyanaDurova Everything about **Implicit Flow** shoud be explained [here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth).

Comment: Could you help with code
'var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>{
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("_username", username),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("_password", password),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("_csrf_token","pepaSlWcBp6HqBQD0_0gFzZupRO1XQXlUv31JoZocoE",
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("_remember_me", "on")}
);'

Comment: '< form action = "/api/oauth/v2/auth/login_check" method = "post" >
< label class = "b-form_label" > Fill out the form below to Sign In! <  / label >
< input type = "hidden" name = "_csrf_token" value = "pepaSlWcBp6HqBQD0_0gFzZupRO1XQXlUv31JoZocoE" /  >  < fieldset class = "b-form_unit" >
< input class = "b-form_input" id = "username" name = "_username" value = "" required = "required" placeholder = "Username:" style = "margin-top: 10px;" >
<  / fieldset >'

Comment: '< fieldset class = "b-form_unit" >
< input class = "b-form_input" type = "password" id = "password" name = "_password" required = "required" placeholder = "Password:" >
<  / fieldset >
< fieldset class = "b-form_unit" >
< input id = "remember_me" type = "checkbox" name = "_remember_me" class = "b-checkbox" value = "on" >
< label class = "b-checkbox-name" for  = "remember_me" >
< span class = "pseudo-checkbox" >  <  / span >
< span class = "label-text" > Remember me <  / span >
<  / label >
<  / fieldset >
<  / form >'

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to past long code text, so make it in few comments.. 

My form have different fields, how to change your code for it?

And what is _csrf_token?

Answer (score 0):

So, if there are the CSRF token on the login form, then it's no way to get access token with implicit flow.